# How to share one Windows Live Mail account for all users

Tags: windows-live-mail

Is there a way to setup Windows Live Mail with one email account and have it automatically shared for all users without having to configure Live Mail for each user?  I want all users to be sharing the same email address in Live Mail without having to manually configure each one.

If not, how can I programatically setup accounts in Windows Live Mail.